# Firebase RealTime Database expand all missing

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

from the last week when I opened my firebase real time database I cant find the option expand and collapse all data as in picture
expand all missing:

[image]

How I can get this option back?

Comment: Firebase recently updated the console. You can file a bug report (or feature request if that was removed intentionally) to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact)

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

We just released a new version of our data viewer for the Realtime Database. While this viewer has many improvements and should also be a lot faster, there may be some features that we missed - like the option to expand all nodes in one go that you mention. Our team is actively monitoring for feedback on such regressions, so thanks for the report!

If you find more of them, you can either post them here, on our [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/L-gb3vS0mUQ) mailing list, or reach out directly to our support team with a [bug report or feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).